# JessRules - Iteration over an ArrayList

Tags: jess

there is my dilemna :

```
    (defrule A15_test   
    ?list <- (accumulate (bind ?ll (new java.util.ArrayList))   ;; initializer
                (?ll add ?id)                             ;; action
                 ?ll                                        ;; result
                 (P (ID_Jess ?id) (m ?ref&:(neq ?ref nil)))
                ) ;; CE 
   (foreach ?l ?list
        (printout t "l:" ?l " "  crlf)
    )

 => 
   (printout t "FIRE ! c:" (?list toString) " end.  " crlf)
```

Which gives the following error :

```
Jess reported an error in routine Jesp.parsePattern.
  Message: Bad slot value at token '('.
  Program text: ( defrule A15_test ?list <- ( accumulate ( bind ?ll ( new java.util.ArrayList ) ) ( ?ll add ?id ) ?ll ( P ( ID_Jess ?id ) ( m ?ref & : ( neq ?ref nil ) ) ) ) ( foreach ?l ?list (  at line 80 in file <eval pipe>.
    at jess.Jesp.error(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Jesp.a(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Jesp.a(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Jesp.a(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Jesp.a(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Jesp.if(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Jesp.parseDefrule(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Jesp.parseExpression(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Jesp.promptAndParseOneExpression(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Jesp.parse(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Rete.eval(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Rete.eval(Unknown Source)
    at jesslanguage.JessExecutor.executeJess(JessExecutor.java:30)
    at Main.testJessRules(Main.java:293)
    at Main.main(Main.java:62)
```

Clearly, the foreach doesn't like my ?list.
Note that if I remove it, the (foreach XXX), it all works fine and give :

```
FIRE ! c:[p1, p3, p4] 
FIRE ! c:[p1, p3, p4]
```

(Which I'm try to group in ONE fire accumulating or counting on the elements of the list)

Anybody knows how to iterate over a Java ArrayList directly from Jess ?

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration code is fine. The problem is you're including it in a place where only patterns (conditional elements) are allowed, not function calls. You need to move the "foreach" to the right-hand side of the rule.

Comment: No functions can be called in the LHS ? I would like to use the function to manipulate some information before deciding to fire or not. I.e., regrouper les fires in a "forall" second order logic.

Comment: Your functions would have to part of a conditional element. See, for example, the "test" CE.